# What does the message "shutdown via gdm" mean?

Tags: linux, unix

While going through the `syslog` file, I found a message like `shutdown via gdm` What does this mean? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GDM](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gdm) is **GNOME Display Manager**. If you have GNOME on your machine, and you shutdown your machine through the GUI, this message `Shutdown via GDM` is seen in `syslog`. It wont be seen if you shutdown via command line.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you (or someone) has clicked "shutdown" in the log-in screen.